# ui grid 400 error in chrome dev tools when loading image in celltemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Has anyone seen this problem and know what's going on?  If you load this with chrome dev tools open you will see a 400 error ( Bad Request )
http://plnkr.co/edit/fRhBgC4SmPYL8udb007y?p=preview

The problem appears when you use an row.entity.imgurl inside the cellTemplate.

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.grid']);

testApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.grid = {
    rowHeight: 50,
    data: [{
      name: 'Test',
      label: 'Suwako Moriya',
      imgurl: 'http://i.imgur.com/945LPEw.png'
    }],
    columnDefs: [
          { field: 'name'},
          { field: 'label', displayName: 'Name',
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" title="TOOLTIP"><img  alt="{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}"  src="{{row.entity.imgurl}}"/>'
          }
    ]};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ng-src="{{row.entity.imgurl}}"
```

Comment: That solved it - thank you!  looked up ng-src and here is what it says...Using AngularJS markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until AngularJS replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

The buggy way to write it:

<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description"/>
The correct way to write it:

<img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}" alt="Description" />   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc